# Not able add the second line to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python scripting. There is a file which contains data below

```
Cascade.from = testvalue1 
cascade.from1 = testvalue2
```

The above context is in test.txt. I have written a below code in order to put this in dictionary and fetch it later code is as below

```
myvalue = {}
with open('test.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        name, val = line.split('=')
        myvalue[name] = str(val.strip())
        print myvalue
```

after running the above code, I see only  below data 
`{"cascade.from": "testvalue1"}` 
it's not reading the next line and it's not getting added to the  dictionary. 
My expectation is: `{"cascade.from": "testvalue1", "cascade.from1": "testvalue2"}`. So that  when call `myvalue["cascade.from1"]` it should retrun be `testvalue2`
Could anyone let me know what am missing here?

The above was just a small piece inside a function, here is my code complete thing

```
def readlocalfile():
        os.chdir(sub_dir)
        print ("prinintng current directory" + os.getcwd())
        file = open(config_file,'r')
        file_read = file.readlines()
        myvars = {}
        with open(config_file) as myfile:
             for line in myfile:
                   name, var = line.split("=")
                   myvars[name] = str(var.strip())
                   print myvars
                   replace_val = myvars["cascade.from1"]
                   print ("the base value is "+ replace_val)
```

Iam calling this function outside, which throws a KeyError

Comment: You are missing `:` after `... as myfile`. However this should lead to a crash and not the problem you are getting. I added `:` and tried the code and it works for me.

Comment: @Cleared After  as myfile  i have added : but still not working for me  :(

Comment: Is this realy the code you have tried? Is it a pure copy of your code or have you "rewritten" it just for this question? The reason im asking is because you have had two typos so far, both which would have caused crashes. I have tried the code above and it works for me...

Comment: I try the code you give and it works for me on python2.7. Can you put some lines of 'test.txt' ?

Comment: @Cleared Jann has edited the code, so it should work now just fine!

Comment: I have also tried the code in Python 2.7.12, works fine. Do test.txt contain anything else except for the two lines?

Comment: I have added the actual code which am using please have look

Comment: There we go, thanks for the updated, The error that caused the problem was not in your original code, but in the last two lines of the full code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time in the loop, you are trying to read

```
myvars["cascade.from1"]
```

But the key `cascade.from1` does not exists in the first time in the loop, since you only have loaded the first line which is `Cascade.from` (the key `cascade.from1` is created the second time in the loop) And thats why you get an error and your program craches at the row `replace_val= myvars["cascade.from1"]` the first time. Therefore `print myvars` is only run the first time in the loop, when you only have read the first line in the file.

To use

```
replace_val= myvars["cascade.from1"]
```

You have to move it outside the loop since ince myvars does not contain the key `cascade.from1` inside the loop the first time:

```
def readlocalfile():
    os.chdir(sub_dir)
    print ("prinintng current directory" + os.getcwd())
    file=open(config_file,'r')
    file_read=file.readlines()
    myvars = {}
    with open(config_file) as myfile:
        for line in myfile:
            name, var = line.split("=")
            myvars[name] = str(var.strip())
            print myvars
        replace_val= myvars["cascade.from1"]
        print ("the base value is "+ replace_val)
```

Comment: thanks for clarification , but i need to read both line.  how will i do that  ?

Comment: By removing `replace_val= myvars["cascade.from1"]` and `print ("the base value is "+ replace_val)` you will read both lines. What are you trying to do when you do `replace_val= myvars["cascade.from1"]`?

Comment: Am trying to retrieve the value for cascade.from1 so when call replace_val should contain testvalu1

Comment: See my updated answer. You have to move the two last lines to outside the loop (indent them to the left). Inside the loop `myvars` is not yet completed, but outside it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i got this fixed it was my  bad i should have searched the values outside the for loop.  Thanks once again its working.